# R: Selecting Rows Based on Conditions Stored in a Data Frame

Tags: r, random, where-clause, categories, data-manipulation

I am working with the R programming language.

I have the following dataset:

```
num_var_1 <- rnorm(1000, 10, 1)
num_var_2 <- rnorm(1000, 10, 5)
num_var_3 <- rnorm(1000, 10, 10)
num_var_4 <- rnorm(1000, 10, 10)
num_var_5 <- rnorm(1000, 10, 10)

factor_1 <- c("A","B", "C")
factor_2 <- c("AA","BB", "CC")
factor_3 <- c("AAA","BBB", "CCC", "DDD")
factor_4 <- c("AAAA","BBBB", "CCCC", "DDDD", "EEEE")
factor_5 <- c("AAAAA","BBBBB", "CCCCC", "DDDDD", "EEEEE", "FFFFFF")

factor_var_1 <- as.factor(sample(factor_1, 1000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.3, 0.5, 0.2)))
factor_var_2 <-  as.factor(sample(factor_2, 1000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.5, 0.3, 0.2)))
factor_var_3 <-  as.factor(sample(factor_3, 1000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.5, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1)))
factor_var_4 <-  as.factor(sample(factor_4, 1000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.5, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1)))
factor_var_5 <-  as.factor(sample(factor_4, 1000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1)))

id = 1:1000

my_data = data.frame(id,num_var_1, num_var_2, num_var_3, num_var_4, num_var_5, factor_var_1, factor_var_2, factor_var_3, factor_var_4, factor_var_5)


> head(my_data)
  id num_var_1 num_var_2 num_var_3 num_var_4  num_var_5 factor_var_1 factor_var_2 factor_var_3 factor_var_4 factor_var_5
1  1  9.439524  5.021006  4.883963  8.496925  11.965498            B           AA          AAA         CCCC         AAAA
2  2  9.769823  4.800225 12.369379  6.722429  16.501132            B           AA          AAA         AAAA         AAAA
3  3 11.558708  9.910099  4.584108 -4.481653  16.710042            C           AA          BBB         AAAA         CCCC
4  4 10.070508  9.339124 22.192276  3.027154  -2.841578            B           CC          DDD         BBBB         AAAA
5  5 10.129288 -2.746714 11.741359 35.984902 -10.261096            B           AA          AAA         DDDD         DDDD
6  6 11.715065 15.202867  3.847317  9.625850  32.053261            B           AA          CCC         BBBB         EEEE
```

Based on the answer provided from a previous question ([R: Randomly Sampling Mixed Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70501952/r-randomly-sampling-mixed-variables)), I learned how to randomly take samples from this data:

```
library(dplyr)
 library(purrr)

# calc the ratio of choosing variable
var_num <- ncol(my_data) - 1
var_select_ratio <- sum(1:var_num) / (var_num^2)

num_func <- function(vec, iter_num) {
  random_val = runif(iter_num, min(vec), max(vec))
  is_select <- sample(c(NA, 1), iter_num, 
                      prob = c(1 - var_select_ratio, var_select_ratio), replace = TRUE)
  return(random_val * is_select)
}

fac_func <- function(vec, iter_num) {
  nlevels <- sample.int(length(levels(vec)), iter_num, replace = TRUE)
  is_select <- sample(c(0, 1), iter_num, 
                      prob = c(1 - var_select_ratio, var_select_ratio), replace = TRUE)
  out <- map2(nlevels, is_select,  # NOTE: this process isn't vectorized
              function(nl, ic){
                if(ic == 0) NULL else sample(vec, nl)
              })
  return(out)
}

integ_func <- function(vec, iter_num) {
  if(is.factor(vec)) fac_func(vec, iter_num) else num_func(vec, iter_num)
}
```

After these functions are defined, you can now take random samples:

```
res <- my_data %>% 
  select(-id) %>% 
  map(~ integ_func(.x, iter_num = 10)) %>%  # use the func with each cols
  as_tibble()   

# if you want to paste factor_var
res2 <- res %>% 
  mutate_if(is.list, function(col) map_chr(col, function(cell) paste(sort(cell), collapse = " "))) %>%   # paste
  mutate_if(is.character, function(col) na_if(col, ""))  # replace "" to NA
```

This produces the following results:

```
 > res2 = data.frame(res2)

> res2
   num_var_1 num_var_2  num_var_3 num_var_4  num_var_5 factor_var_1 factor_var_2    factor_var_3             factor_var_4             factor_var_5
1   8.251683 27.791314  30.525573  33.95768   2.388074            B         <NA>             AAA                     AAAA                     DDDD
2   9.012602        NA         NA        NA  20.236515            A        AA BB            <NA>                     <NA>                     BBBB
3         NA 16.778085  28.097324   5.69020         NA            B           BB     CCC DDD DDD                     <NA> AAAA BBBB CCCC CCCC CCCC
4  12.838667 -3.694075  13.411877  -2.20004         NA         <NA>     AA AA BB     AAA BBB CCC                     <NA> AAAA AAAA BBBB CCCC DDDD
5         NA        NA  11.922439  17.63757         NA          A B     AA AA BB            <NA>                AAAA AAAA                     BBBB
6  12.768595        NA  28.507646        NA         NA            C           AA     BBB DDD DDD      AAAA AAAA CCCC DDDD AAAA AAAA BBBB EEEE EEEE
7         NA        NA -20.424906        NA  20.147004         <NA>        AA AA            <NA> AAAA AAAA AAAA CCCC EEEE                     <NA>
8         NA  6.299722   8.569485  24.82825 -17.715862         <NA>           BB AAA AAA BBB CCC                     <NA>                BBBB EEEE
9  10.846757        NA         NA        NA         NA        A B C     AA BB CC            <NA>                     <NA>                BBBB BBBB
10        NA  4.663916  22.335404        NA         NA        B B C        AA BB AAA AAA AAA DDD AAAA AAAA CCCC EEEE EEEE                     <NA>
```

**My Question:** Is it possible to select all rows from `my_data` based on the values from the 10th row of `res_2`?

For example:

```
#pseudocode 

final_result <- my_data[which(my_data$num_var_1 < res2[10,1] & my_data$num_var_2 < res2[10,2] & my_data$num_var_3 < res2[10,3] & my_data$num_var_4 < res2[10,4] & my_data$num_var_5 < res2[10,5] & my_data$factor_var_1 == res2[10,6] & my_data$factor_var_2 == res2[10,7] & my_data$factor_var_3 == res2[10,8] & my_data$factor_var_4 == res2[10,9] & my_data$factor_var_5 == res2[10,10]), ]
```

This of course does not work and returns an empty result:

```
[1] id           num_var_1    num_var_2    num_var_3    num_var_4    num_var_5    factor_var_1 factor_var_2 factor_var_3 factor_var_4 factor_var_5
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

This would be the equivalent of writing (see 10th row of `res_2`):

```
final_result <- my_data[which(my_data$num_var_2 < 4.66 & my_data$num_var_3 < 22.33 &  my_data$factor_var_1 %in% c( "B", "C") & my_data$factor_var_2 %in% c( "AA", "BB") & my_data$factor_var_3 %in% c( "AAA", "DDD") & my_data$factor_var_4 %in% c( "AAAA", "CCCC", "EEEE" )), ]
```

**Can someone please show me how to do this?**

Thanks!

**Note:** In this case, if a variable is `<NA>`, it would mean select ALL factors in that column. E.g. If factor_var_4 was assigned as , it would mean `select ALL rows where factor_var_4 = AAAA or BBBB or CCCC or DDDD or EEEE`

Comment: what if you replace the `&` with `|` in `final_result`

Comment: @ Mike: Thank you for your reply! I tried this - but I do not think that this worked unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

There are two possible solutions:

1. revert (or don't do this at all) a pasting step that converts a vector of strings into a single string. Vector of strings will allow you to use `%in%` operator that I believe you are looking for.
2. use a string in another string comparison

AD 1:

Like I said earlier - it would be easier to don't do it at all (i.e. use `res` instead of `res2`) but your question explicitly mention usage of `res2`. Therefore some *revert* step is needed:

```
res3 <- res2 %>% 
  mutate(
    across(where(is.character), function(vec) unlist(lapply(vec, strsplit, split = " "), recursive = FALSE))
  )
```

Here's the result (note randomness in the data):

```
> res3
# A tibble: 10 × 10
   num_var_1 num_var_2 num_var_3 num_var_4 num_var_5 factor_var_1 factor_var_2 factor_var_3 factor_var_4 factor_var_5
       <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl> <list>       <list>       <list>       <list>       <list>      
 1     NA        NA        13.1       NA       NA    <chr [1]>    <chr [3]>    <chr [1]>    <chr [1]>    <chr [1]>   
 2     13.2      NA        17.3       39.4     15.4  <chr [1]>    <chr [1]>    <chr [1]>    <chr [4]>    <chr [4]>   
 3      8.52     NA        NA         NA       NA    <chr [1]>    <chr [2]>    <chr [3]>    <chr [1]>    <chr [3]>   
 4     11.5      NA        31.8       NA       NA    <chr [3]>    <chr [1]>    <chr [1]>    <chr [2]>    <chr [2]>   
 5     NA        NA        33.4       NA       30.1  <chr [1]>    <chr [2]>    <chr [1]>    <chr [1]>    <chr [1]>   
 6      7.21     -2.56      2.42      34.6     NA    <chr [2]>    <chr [2]>    <chr [3]>    <chr [2]>    <chr [5]>   
 7     12.9      NA        -4.54      13.4     17.5  <chr [1]>    <chr [1]>    <chr [1]>    <chr [5]>    <chr [2]>   
 8     10.8      NA       -19.4       NA       13.8  <chr [3]>    <chr [1]>    <chr [1]>    <chr [5]>    <chr [1]>   
 9      7.37     16.6      NA         33.3     NA    <chr [1]>    <chr [2]>    <chr [1]>    <chr [4]>    <chr [5]>   
10     NA         6.75     NA        -11.9      7.04 <chr [1]>    <chr [1]>    <chr [4]>    <chr [1]>    <chr [1]>
```

Now goes the final comparison code. I noticed that you skipped all the `NA` in the `res2` which simply mean you use a `TRUE` value in the comparison.

```
f_comp_in <- function(x, y) if (is.na(y[[1]])) T else x %in% y[[1]]
f_comp_l <- function(x, y) if (is.na(y)) T else x < y
my_data %>% 
  filter(
    f_comp_in(factor_var_1, res3[10, "factor_var_1"][[1]][[1]]) &
      f_comp_in(factor_var_2, res3[10, "factor_var_2"][[1]][[1]]) &
      f_comp_in(factor_var_3, res3[10, "factor_var_3"][[1]][[1]]) &
      f_comp_in(factor_var_4, res3[10, "factor_var_4"][[1]][[1]]) &
      f_comp_in(factor_var_5, res3[10, "factor_var_5"][[1]][[1]]) &
      f_comp_l(num_var_1, res3[10, "num_var_1"][[1]]) &
      f_comp_l(num_var_2, res3[10, "num_var_2"][[1]]) &
      f_comp_l(num_var_3, res3[10, "num_var_3"][[1]]) &
      f_comp_l(num_var_4, res3[10, "num_var_4"][[1]]) &
      f_comp_l(num_var_5, res3[10, "num_var_5"][[1]])
  )
```

Mind the list indexing. `res2` as well as `res3` is a `tibble`, therefore you need to run `tibble_object[<row>, <col>][[1]]` to get the value (`tibble_object[<row>, <col>]` would return a `tibble`). Moreover, all the `factor_var_X` are lists inside a list - one additional `[[1]]` is required to get the value(s).

Note that you can also do `strsplit()` within a comparison function without the need of creating `res3` object (memory efficient):

```
f_comp_in <- function(x, y) if (is.na(y)) T else x %in% strsplit(y, split = " ")[[1]]
f_comp_l <- function(x, y) if (is.na(y)) T else x < y
my_data %>% 
  filter(
    f_comp_in(factor_var_1, res2[10, "factor_var_1"][[1]]) &
      f_comp_in(factor_var_2, res2[10, "factor_var_2"][[1]]) &
      f_comp_in(factor_var_3, res2[10, "factor_var_3"][[1]]) &
      f_comp_in(factor_var_4, res2[10, "factor_var_4"][[1]]) &
      f_comp_in(factor_var_5, res2[10, "factor_var_5"][[1]]) &
      f_comp_l(num_var_1, res2[10, "num_var_1"][[1]]) &
      f_comp_l(num_var_2, res2[10, "num_var_2"][[1]]) &
      f_comp_l(num_var_3, res2[10, "num_var_3"][[1]]) &
      f_comp_l(num_var_4, res2[10, "num_var_4"][[1]]) &
      f_comp_l(num_var_5, res2[10, "num_var_5"][[1]])
  )
```

AD 2:

Unfortunately, base string comparison with `grepl()` is not vectorised thus you need to execute it inside a for loop.

```
f_comp_in <- function(x, y) if (is.na(y)) T else vapply(x, grepl, logical(1), x = y)
f_comp_l <- function(x, y) if (is.na(y)) T else x < y
my_data %>% 
  filter(
    f_comp_in(factor_var_1, res2[10, "factor_var_1"][[1]]) &
      f_comp_in(factor_var_2, res2[10, "factor_var_2"][[1]]) &
      f_comp_in(factor_var_3, res2[10, "factor_var_3"][[1]]) &
      f_comp_in(factor_var_4, res2[10, "factor_var_4"][[1]]) &
      f_comp_in(factor_var_5, res2[10, "factor_var_5"][[1]]) &
      f_comp_l(num_var_1, res2[10, "num_var_1"][[1]]) &
      f_comp_l(num_var_2, res2[10, "num_var_2"][[1]]) &
      f_comp_l(num_var_3, res2[10, "num_var_3"][[1]]) &
      f_comp_l(num_var_4, res2[10, "num_var_4"][[1]]) &
      f_comp_l(num_var_5, res2[10, "num_var_5"][[1]])
  )
```

Comment: Thank  you so much for your answer! I will try this when I get home! Can you please include an example as to how someone would use these functions? Thank you so much!

Comment: I used your code and I got the following output:  [1] id           num_var_1    num_var_2    num_var_3    num_var_4    num_var_5    factor_var_1 factor_var_2 factor_var_3
[10] factor_var_4 factor_var_5
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

Comment: Am I doing something wrong? Thanks!

Comment: As it includes randomness in the data please consider relaxing some conditions (e.g. apply it only on one factor and one numeric col only). I have to admit that I also ended up with an empty data.frame object but to me it's due to how rigorous the conditions are

Answer (score 2):

Using `purrr` and `stringi` within the `tidyverse`

**Variant with `%in%`**

```
library(stringi)
library(tidyverse)

row10 <- res2[10,]

check_num_func <- function(num){ 
  return(all(is.na(row10[1:5]) | num<row10[1:5]))
}

check_factor_func <- function(fac){
  result <- map2_lgl(fac, stri_extract_all_words(row10[6:10]), `%in%`)
  return(all(ifelse(is.na(row10[6:10]), TRUE, result)))
}

my_data_filtered <- my_data %>% 
  mutate(check_num = apply(my_data %>% select(num_var_1:num_var_5), 1, check_num_func),
         check_fac = apply(my_data %>% select(factor_var_1:factor_var_5), 1, check_factor_func)) %>% 
  filter(check_num & check_fac) %>% 
  select(-check_num, -check_fac)
```

**Variant with `is_in`**

```
library(stringi)
library(tidyverse)

row10 <- res2[10,]

check_num_func <- function(num){ 
  return(all(is.na(row10[1:5]) | num<row10[1:5]))
}

check_factor_func <- function(fac){
  result <- map2_lgl(fac, stri_extract_all_words(row10[6:10]), is_in)
  return(all(ifelse(is.na(row10[6:10]), TRUE, result)))
}

my_data_filtered <- my_data %>% 
  mutate(check_num = apply(my_data %>% select(num_var_1:num_var_5), 1, check_num_func),
         check_fac = apply(my_data %>% select(factor_var_1:factor_var_5), 1, check_factor_func)) %>% 
  filter(check_num & check_fac) %>% 
  select(-check_num, -check_fac)
```

**My output (displaying only the `head`)**

```
> res2[10,]
# A tibble: 1 x 10
  num_var_1 num_var_2 num_var_3 num_var_4 num_var_5 factor_var_1 factor_var_2 factor_var_3 factor_var_4 factor_var_5       
      <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>        <chr>        <chr>        <chr>        <chr>              
1        NA        NA      11.0        NA      14.7 NA           NA           AAA          NA           AAAA BBBB BBBB CCCC
> my_data_filtered %>% head
  id num_var_1 num_var_2  num_var_3  num_var_4 num_var_5 factor_var_1 factor_var_2 factor_var_3 factor_var_4 factor_var_5
1  3 11.846715 11.509069  10.840912  10.114141 11.554633            B           CC          AAA         BBBB         AAAA
2  6 10.690189 -1.335147  -1.028286  13.884934 12.047721            B           AA          AAA         BBBB         AAAA
3 12 10.022039 10.851465   8.905692  18.650092  7.823362            B           BB          AAA         DDDD         AAAA
4 15  9.156137  1.179674 -10.866282  20.058736  4.543155            A           BB          AAA         AAAA         BBBB
5 43 10.160805  9.347031 -10.808265  -2.588934  4.912227            B           CC          AAA         AAAA         BBBB
6 68  9.130132 10.531478 -20.125775 -10.083095 12.016262            A           BB          AAA         DDDD         BBBB
```

---

**Explanation**

```
row10 <- res2[10,] # take 10th row of res2
```

This next function checks if all the conditions on the numeric columns are fulfilled, given a numeric vector of length 5.
`row10[1:5]` is `row10` limited to the numeric columns. I use `all` to check if all elements of are `TRUE`.
I get a logical element.

```
check_num_func <- function(num){                   # num = numeric vector of length 5
  return(all(is.na(row10[1:5]) | num<row10[1:5]))  # check cell by cell if it's either NA in row10 or if the cell in num < corresponding cell of row10
}
```

This next function checks if all the conditions on the character columns are fulfilled, given a character vector of length 5.
`row10[6:10]` is `row10` limited to the character columns.
I use `stringi::stri_extract_all_words` to separate the factors in the strings and put them in a list.
Then I `purrr:map2_lgl` on `fac` and this list, using the `is_in` function from `magrittr` (equivalent to `~.x%in%.y`), which gives a logical vector. `map2_lgl` applies `is_in` to each element of `fac` and the corresponding element of `result` to check if the factor is in the factors proposed by `row10`.
For the `NA` cases I use `ifelse`, replacing the result of `map2_lgl` with `TRUE` when `row10[6:10]` is `NA`. I use `all` again to see if all elements are `TRUE`.
I get a logical element.

```
check_factor_func <- function(fac){ # fac = char vector of length 5
  result <- map2_lgl(fac, stri_extract_all_words(row10[6:10]), is_in)
  return(all(ifelse(is.na(row10[6:10]), TRUE, result)))
}
```

Then I use these 2 functions to check the conditions for all the rows using `apply` on the rows, selecting the relevant columns for `apply`, which I can then use to `filter`.

```
my_data_filtered <- my_data %>% 
  mutate(check_num = apply(my_data %>% select(num_var_1:num_var_5), 1, check_num_func),
         check_fac = apply(my_data %>% select(factor_var_1:factor_var_5), 1, check_factor_func)) %>% # create new variables applying each function to corresponding columns, row by row
  filter(check_num & check_fac) %>% 
  select(-check_num, -check_fac) # filter with my variables and remove filtering columns
```

Comment: @ Valkyr : Thank you so much for your answer! I tried your code and got the following error:

Comment: ! Problem while computing `check_fac = apply(my_data %>% select(factor_var_1:factor_var_5), 1,
  check_factor_func)`.
Caused by error in `as_mapper()`:
! object 'is_in' not found
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong? Thank you so much!

Comment: It looks like you don't have the function `is_in` in your environment. Did you load `library(tidyverse)`? You can also try replacing `is_in` with  ` %in% ` (remove the spaces around it) inside the definition of `check_factor_func`

Comment: I think I do have tidyverse loaded? I attached a screenshot here: https://imgur.com/a/IxjXOM5

Comment: I tried the replacement of "is_in" with ` %in% `  ... I am now getting a new error:

Comment: Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `check_fac = apply(my_data %>% select(factor_var_1:factor_var_5), 1,
  check_factor_func)`.
Caused by error in `as_mapper()`:
! object ' %in% ' not found
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: I will keep trying to fix this! Thank you for your help!

Comment: Yes remove the spaces around. I will update my code

Comment: I put the variant with %in% on top of the post. But I suspect you have something wrong with your installation of tidyverse (you should have other packages installed in the list, like dplyr, purrr...). You could try to reinstall tidyverse and reload it with `install.packages("tidyverse")` then `library(tidyverse)`. Then retry the variant with `is_in`. If it **still** doesn't work, install and load magrittr manually with `install.packages("magrittr")` and `library(magrittr)` and retry the `is_in` variant.

Comment: By the way, make sure you have stringi installed and loaded. Otherwise you cannost use my code. `install.packages("stringi")` then `library(stringi)`

Comment: Thank you again for your edits! I am so sorry to keep asking you questions - now the code is running, but an empty output is being produced: head(my_data_filtered)
 [1] id           num_var_1    num_var_2    num_var_3    num_var_4    num_var_5    factor_var_1 factor_var_2 factor_var_3 factor_var_4 factor_var_5
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

Comment: Is this because of the random nature of the data? thanks!

Comment: It is possibly due to the randomness (maybe no rows fulfilled your criteria). I tried running the code again and got 2 rows only this time. You can try rerunning it a few times, from the beginning, generating new dataframes, see if it outputs something.